# More than 5300 message to my website had a JS content

Tags: javascript, server-side-attacks

I create a website, and I receive more than 5300 message in 1 day, had a JavaScript content

I resolve the problem to stop the messages adding the CAPTCHA

But I want to know what's is this

The content of message is:

```
javascript:window.top._arachni_js_namespace_taint_tracer.log_execution_flow_sink()
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone was probably using [Arachni](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni) to check your site for vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, for you the CAPTCHA can stop it ?